# How to display properly Simplified Chinese ideograms using Google Web Fonts' Noto Sans CJK SC?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts, google-webfonts

I want to display some Chinese Simplified Characters using Google Web Fonts' Noto Sans CJK SC but it doesn't seems to work. I read the guide on Google Fonts' and properly followed their instructions but unfortunately my characters are still displayed using the default police of the browser (Chrome). How can I fix that please ?
Here is my link : [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/dfe7433b16957793ad7ab8769cc52adb)
Thanks in advance for your help.
Kindest regards,
BK

Comment: You have a typo: `font:family:'Noto Sans SC';` should be `font-family: 'Noto Sans SC';`

Comment: djangodude thanks for your answer ! I fixed it but it doesn't works although that... (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvqdYE) @djangodude

Comment: Fixing your Dabblet like @djangodude says fixes it. Your Codepen doesn't work because CORS prevents the font from being downloaded. Please update your post to either a correct Dabblet or Codepen if there are any other problems.

Comment: Hi @RoeIN ! Thx for your answer. Here is my fixed Dabblet : [link](http://dabblet.com/gist/c5e6d922ad457cf2f94062270b1e1bf5)

Comment: Even when I test the same code on localhost it doesn't works